# Trying to use eclipse hadoop plugin to connect hadoop inside minikube

Tags: eclipse, kubernetes, hadoop, minikube

I am using helm and minikube to install hadoop and hive on centos7.9 , and the status of pod and service:

[status of my pod and service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCIUf.jpg)

Next , I want to connect hadoop using eclipse hadoop plugin , but there is a problem:

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxJA3.jpg)

I don't have a Hadoop installation diretory because it is installed inside minikube , and this setting can't go on without diretory.

I want to know if there is a way to connect my hadoop inside minikube

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse uses hdfs commands to connect to the Namenode URI. You need to still *download* Hadoop binaries, not "install" them.

Besides that, Kubernetes Ingress only works for HTTP/S, whereas Namenode uses its own RPC protocol for communications, so you won't be able to directly access it from outside the cluster without a TCP Proxy or using `kubectl port-forward`

FWIW, replacing HDFS with MinIO or Ozone would be better options for using with Hive (or Presto) within Kubernetes